# How To pass Field Value (like textbox) from Partial view to other Partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can you help on this

I have two Partial Views in the page,  the First Partial View have (Input Text and Submit Button )

Whenever the user Press Submit Button (from PartialView1 ) , I would like to ready the input Text from PartialView2

can you please help on How I can Read the Partial View1's Input Text  from PartialView2 when Pressing the PartialView1's submit button ?
More specifically :reading that value from the "Action"  that is rendering the PartialView2

more Details:
It is something like that : read the values from all textboxes in partialview1 and assign the all content into textbox2 in partial2 when press submit button from PartialView1

below is an example

this is my main View index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <%Html.RenderAction("ActionSenderForPartial1", "Controllername"); %>
    </div>
    <h2>Result</h2>
    <div>
        <%Html.RenderAction("ActionReceiverForpartial2", "Controllername"); %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the PartialView 1 "Partial1"

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.UIField>>" %>
<form  method="post">

<%:Html.TextBox("TextBox1") %>
<%:Html.TextBox("TextBox2") %>
           .
           .
<%:Html.TextBox("TextBoxN") %>
 <p>
            <button name="btnaction" value="search">Search</button>

               <button name="btnaction" value="cancel">Cancel</button>

        </p>

</form>
```

for PartialView2: "Partial2.ascx"

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<%:Html.TextBox("TextBox2") %>

The actions "" & "" :

 [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult ActionSenderForPartial1()
        {

            return PartialView();
        }


[ChildActionOnly]

        public ActionResult ActionReceiverForpartial2(string btnaction)
        {
            string _searchQuery = string.Empty;
            --How to read the all TextBoxes contents from PartialView1 and assign the concatenated values to the TextBox2 at this partialview2

            return PartialView();
        }
```

In case there is many options I would highly appreciate to mention advising the best one  as I am new in MVC.

Thanks so much

if any actual example will be highly appreciated

Please Note: i Have an idea on how to do it by Ajax but I would to do it without using Ajax .

Many Thanks

Nahed

Comment: this is going to have to be done on the client with javascript.  Once the whole page is rendered , the client does not care what was defined as a partial view of layout or view , it is just an html doc at the end.  And can be treated as such with javascript

Comment: Are you posting back to your action when the submit is clicked or is the intention to do nothing than pass the value down to the other field?

Comment: Hi @SteveNewton Yes I will need to post back in the action please see the updated question for clarification, many thanks

Comment: OK, a little confused now.  Are you wanting to display content in results based on some server logic you are going to run with input from the initial data caputure prior to pressing submit?